# Store the complex object and maintain it across different state

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am having `List<Rules>` collection which contains the rules, clicking one of these rule will open one **Pop-Up**.
Pop-Up will contain two button *Update* & *Cancel*.
On click of Update, I am calling an API which will do needful task.

My concern is Rules will also contain set of different object, and each of having the nested child objects.
On **Pop-Up** whenever I try to edit particular things inside the Rules, Again there is *Update* & *Cancel* button to store that particular step.
So it is the chaining of object which I must need to remember so that on cancel click I am able to retain its previous step.

I have object of type  `Observables`.
`rules$: Observable<Array<Rules>>`

I want the best possible solution to maintain the chain-of-objects of Rules while editing the Rules.

I have tried by implementing:
Stack

But I think there can be better way to solve this.

Any type of input will be useful.